# Certain words with a -ment ending: What is the signification of this ending?

Tags: participe-présent

I learned about "participe present" and "gérondif", but I am exploring some words with the *-ent* ending. For example the word *chargement* in my phone, which probably means "loading".

As I assume, if the "participe present (-*ant*) of a  verb can be used as an adjective (or maybe it is the "gérondif", I haven't understood yet), for instance "*un garçon, vivant dans cette maison*", then this ending *-ent* is used to make a noun.

However, please explain what is the grammar behind this ending.

Comment: Chargement's suffix isn't -ent, it's -ment. -ment is a now unproductive suffix that makes a noun out of a verb, usually meaning the state or the action that results from the verb. "Chargement" comes from the verb charger (to load), and means both the action of loading something, or the result of loading something, i.e. a load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-ent" is the ending of the third person plural of verbs in the present; the suffix that concerns you is "**-ment**"; there are in fact two such suffixes and at least one variant of one of them (-ement).

cf. TLFi:

1. [Suff. formateur de **subst. masc.** à partir d'un rad. **verbal** et parfois d'un **adj.** ou d'un subst.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ment/0)
2. [Suff. formateur de **nombreux adv.**, à partir d'**adj**. le plus souvent.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ment/1)

Not all verbs, adjectives have a corresponding word in -ment, though.

Examples

> charge*r*/charge*ment*, change*r*/change*ment*, place*r*/place*ment*,…
>
> lent/lent*ement*, fin/fin*ement*, long/long**u***ement*, plein/plein*ement*,… rapide/rapidement